# Laravel dhtmlxgantt api ajax $user is null

Tags: ajax, laravel, api, dhtmlx

Trying to get $user->id to filter $tasks by creator and logs gave error.
Help plz

> [2019-06-28 10:52:18] local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'id' of
>   non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to
>   get property 'id' of non-object at
>   /home/vitaliy/Projects/table/app/Http/Controllers/Api/GanttController.php:30)

**GanttController**

```
    public function get(){

    $links = new Link();


    $user = Auth::user();
        $task_user = TaskUser::all()->where('user_id', $user->id);
        $filter_tasks = collect();
        foreach ($task_user as $task){
            $get_task = Task::find($task{'task_id'});
            $filter_tasks[] = $get_task;
        }



    return response()->json([
        "data" => $filter_tasks,
        "links" => $links->all()
    ]);
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::post('/login', 'Api\Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login.login');
Route::get('/tasks/self', 'Api\TaskController@self');
Route::get('/data', 'Api\GanttController@get');
Route::resource('task', 'Api\TaskController');
Route::resource('link', 'Api\LinkController');
```

**view.blde**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
  gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
  gantt.init("gantt_here");
  gantt.load("/api/data");
  var dp = new gantt.dataProcessor("/api");
  dp.init(gantt);
  dp.setTransactionMode("REST");
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an logged in user

Comment: You could try using the `dd()` helper to dump out the currently logged in user. eg. `dd(Auth::user())`. If it's returning `NULL` then no user is currently logged in.

Comment: dd working ok https://gyazo.com/e14f3fd44d04de1cd8ee3ac44b00ccdb
without dd 
https://gyazo.com/89521afd80d0af04a4d94be1a2555f6e
https://gyazo.com/2d9506266bc58e5e42ff489abfe4d548

all time saying that user is null, cant understand why

Comment: Have some one Any thoughts ?